# Can users upload files directly to Google Cloud Storage without authentication?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage

I just set up a simple JS photo uploader on my site. It uploads photos directly to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

I used the code from their official [JavaScript library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-javascript-samples)

But if you look at that code, you'll see that it requires authentication. I'm authenticated and able to upload photos, but I want everyone to be able to just upload their files without signing in to their Google Accounts.

Is that possible?

Comment: I think you're looking for [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs).

Comment: @jterrace, thanks, I've managed to generate a signed URL and access a private object, but how do I upload a new object with a signed URL? I couldn't find any examples.

Comment: Ever figure it out, @Alex ?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a POST policy doc: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument

This will let you build a signed request with various constraints built in (content-length, content-size, etc.), allowing unauthenticated users to upload to your bucket with the given constraints.

Comment: Could you link your answer to some working code please? Would be a great help!